# How to restart server without exit codes after upgrading from mongodb 3.6 to 4.0

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

In upgrading from 3.6, I've shut down the service, run a purge, did the key server and upgrade and this is what versions show as installed:

- MongoDB shell version v4.0.10 git version:
  c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL
  1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016 allocator: tcmalloc modules: none build environment:
     distmod: ubuntu1604
     distarch: x86_64
     target_arch: x86_64 
  Location: /usr/bin/mongo
- db version v4.0.10 git version:
  c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL
  1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016 allocator: tcmalloc modules: none build environment:
     distmod: ubuntu1604
     distarch: x86_64
     target_arch: x86_64 
  Location: /usr/bin/mongod

When I use the line for dbPath that isn't commented out, I get exit status 62.
When I use dbPath: /data/db (a newly created folder), I get exit status 2.
Neither one works, and I don't know how to fix it.  I do not want to delete the database directory, as this is a live site.  Can someone please help me?

I've tried changing the dbPath, as you can see, restarting the server multiple times and it's not working.

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
#   dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:
#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

When I check the status, this is what I get:
root@pottstownrumble:~# sudo service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-05-30 18:57:24 EDT; 8min ago
  Process: 8927 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=62)
 Main PID: 8927 (code=exited, status=62)

May 30 18:57:22 pottstownrumble systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
May 30 18:57:24 pottstownrumble systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=62/n/a
May 30 18:57:24 pottstownrumble systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 30 18:57:24 pottstownrumble systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

last so many lines of /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log:

```
2019-05-30T18:57:23.707-0400 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2019-05-30T18:57:23.736-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-05-30T18:57:23.736-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-05-30T18:57:23.736-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-05-30T18:57:23.736-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-05-30T18:57:23.806-0400 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 before attempting an upgrade to 4.0; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-upgrade-fcv for more details.
2019-05-30T18:57:23.807-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-05-30T18:57:23.807-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-05-30T18:57:23.807-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2019-05-30T18:57:23.807-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down session sweeper thread
2019-05-30T18:57:23.807-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
2019-05-30T18:57:23.819-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Downgrading WiredTiger datafiles.
2019-05-30T18:57:23.970-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1559257043:970434][8927:0x7f305c248a80], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 29/3712 to 30/256
2019-05-30T18:57:24.073-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1559257044:73520][8927:0x7f305c248a80], txn-recover: Recovering log 29 through 30
2019-05-30T18:57:24.134-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1559257044:134293][8927:0x7f305c248a80], txn-recover: Recovering log 30 through 30
2019-05-30T18:57:24.185-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1559257044:185924][8927:0x7f305c248a80], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-05-30T18:57:24.283-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2019-05-30T18:57:24.283-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-05-30T18:57:24.283-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:62
root@pottstownrumble:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-05-30T19:53:30.160-0400 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Check what the log says in `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. I'm guessing it's a permission issue.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha I edited my post to add the last so many lines from the log

Comment: Is this a standalone deployment? Was this previously upgraded before?

Comment: By standalone, I assume you mean on a web server?  I use digital ocean and have it installed there.  I noticed something that may have been a problem:  I had written down versions and it showed mongo --version as 3.6.12 and mongodb --version as 3.2.17 .  Yes, it's probably been upgraded over the years.

Comment: Could you show the output of the current `mongod --version`? This sounds like an issue where MongoDB was not upgraded properly as per https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/, since the error logs indicate that the data files were not upgraded. I think the best way forward is to install a lower MongoDB version (pre-4.0, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-on-linux/) until it can start, then from there follow the detailed upgrade instructions depending on the working version.

Comment: I did mongod --version originally, and it was listed as version 4, but before I did the upgrade it was actually 3.2 (but mongo --version was 3.6, and I wrongly assumed they were the same).  I ended up installing to 3.4, then upgraded to 3.6 fully, then 4.0 fully but lost the data in the end.  The good news is that it was almost all backed up and I was able to restore manually.  Thanks for helping me see my mistakes.